# CPU Frequency seems very high, even in powersave mode - Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: lubuntu, hp, cpufreq, cpupower

I have installed Lubuntu 22.04. on an old `HP 15-db0021ng` notebook.

Everything runs OK, but the CPU frequency appears very high, even when idle. It never drops below **Freq: 56%** and frequently scales to 116% while browsing Instagram or watching YouTube videos.

I installed `cpupower-gui`. By default the governor is `schedutil`. When I set it to `powersave`,  the CPU frequency remains at 56% and overall performance gets slower.

For some reason, when I run the command:

```
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq && paste <(ls *) <(cat *)
```

some lines get shifted, please see below.

Is there an error somewhere that I can possibly fix?

Many thanks in advance!

```
> cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq && paste <(ls *) <(cat *):

> affected_cpus   0 
> bios_limit      2300000
> cat: cpuinfo_cur_freqcpb        1
> : Permission denied
> cpuinfo_cur_freq        2300000
> cpuinfo_max_freq        1300000
> cpuinfo_min_freq        4000
> cpuinfo_transition_latency      0
> freqdomain_cpus 0
> related_cpus    2300000 2100000 1900000 1700000 1500000 1300000 
> scaling_available_frequencies   conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil 
> scaling_available_governors     1662868
> scaling_cur_freq          acpi-cpufreq
> scaling_driver  schedutil
> scaling_governor        2300000
> scaling_max_freq        1300000
> scaling_min_freq        <unsupported>
```

Comment: The schedutil CPU frequency scaling governor tends to be a little "bursty" and the current frequency might be a little high for a moment when your look. For the powersave governor the CPU frequency is as defined by scaling_min_freq, or 1.3 GHz in your example. What really matters is power.

Comment: Thanks. Is it normal though that CPU frequency never drops below 56%, even if no programs are used/apps running etc.?

Comment: The simple answer is yes. The more complicated answer depends on processor make and model and its own internal ability to spin down.